# Does Spark's stage duration exclude time took by killed tasks?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am running a structured streaming job with a trigger execution duration as 10s. All batches are usually completed within 5s but this one batch took 18s to execute.

On Spark UI, I saw that stage duration is 0.7s but one of its task duration is 14s. All other tasks of this stage were completed in 0.6s or less.

Does that mean that stage duration excludes time took by killed tasks?

**Note** -

1. I have speculative execution enabled, and so at a point in time due sluggish performance this task was killed.
   (another attempt succeeded)
2. This task with 14s duration had 14s of GC time.

Comment: 14s or 14ms of GC?

Comment: https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark/spak-ui-meaning-common-parts/read

Comment: 14 seconds of GC which is same as duration of this killed task.